# nodeJS + jslint : where to install for mac OSX?

Tags: macos, node.js, jslint, npm

I've installed nodeJS ( from http://nodejs.org/ ). This has installed nodeJS & npm. Then I run `npm install jslint`.

The package manager create a folder in my current working directory, and place the required file in it.

Then I guess I should do a symlink in my `/usr/local/bin/` folder in order to have a global `jslint` command.

But the whole point is that following that procedure, the jslint files are inside a specific project folder ( that was my current working folder of that moment ), and not in a generic place.

How should I proceed to have a clean installation ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just discovered a `-g` option, witch install the package globally:

```
npm install -g jslint
```

install jslint in `/usr/local/bin/jslint` , and I can now run jslint in the shell directly without having to create a symlink :)

If you are getting installation errors you might need

```
sudo npm install -g jslint
```

although normally that's not required

Comment: As your answer is correct, I suggest you accept it, as the FAQ suggests [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions).

Comment: Just as a note: you really shouldn't need `sudo` for this (I didn't). `npm install -g jslint` should do the trick fine all by itself.

Comment: @ryentzer If you are getting errors installation errors when not using sudo something is wrong with your settings

Comment: @ierax: On OSX, if you use the regular Node.js installer, you _do_ need `sudo` to install packages globally, which are installed below `/usr/local`. By contrast, if you use installers such as `nvm` or `n`, which install Node.js (instances) at the user level, you do not.